# Android SMS Intent Problem

Tags: android, sqlite, sms, android-listview, android-cursor

I'm trying to open the System SMS application with a sms body that is taken from a database.

I'm using `Cursor` to retrieve titles and messages from a `SQLite` database. I have a `smsButton` which will be clicked. When clicked, it will create the sms intent.

My problem is with the body of the message. I want the body to be the msg_content which is retrieved from the database. I tried to have a reference to it but I believe I failed.

here is my last attempt, trying to have a TextView that will take the id of the msg_content layout :

```
//First: DataBase Retrieving :
//fetch a msg from table `t` with id `id`
Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.fetchMessage(t, id); 
String[] columns = {cursor.getColumnName(1), cursor.getColumnName(2)}; 
int[] columnsLayouts = {R.id.title, R.id.msg_content}; //the columns styles
ca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.getBaseContext(), R.layout.msg_items_layout, cursor,columns , columnsLayouts);
lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list); 
lv.setAdapter(ca);

//Here is MY PROBLEM :
TextView msgText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg_content); //same Id as the msg_content column above
smsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            String uri= "smsto:";
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(uri));
            intent.putExtra("sms_body", msgText.getText());
            intent.putExtra("compose_mode", true);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Any way to reference the string of the content ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `findViewById()` on an activity... to get data out of database?

You should be using your `Cursor` to get at your information.

Since you did not bother to provide the actual source code (just a couple of dis-contiguous snippets, AFAICT), it is difficult to give you concrete advice. Taking a random stab at an answer, I would delete `smsButton`, and instead listen for `ListView` item clicks (e.g., `onListItemClick()` if you are implementing a `ListActivity`), then use the supplied `position` to move to the right spot in the `Cursor` and read out the data.